# XPath removing whitespaces in list Python

Tags: python, xpath, export-to-csv

I've trying everything that I know but don't seem to find the solution.

```
import csv
import requests
from lxml import html
from itertools import izip

list_names_atp = []
page = requests.get('http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/rankings/singles')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

list_rank_atp = []
for i in range(0,101):
    result = tree.xpath('//*[@id="rankingDetailAjaxContainer"]/table/tbody/tr[%s]/td[1]/text()'%(i))
    list_rank_atp.append(result)

list_names_atp = []
for i in range(0,101):
    result1 = tree.xpath('//*[@id="rankingDetailAjaxContainer"]/table/tbody/tr[%s]/td[4]/a/text()'%(i))
    list_names_atp.append(result1)

list_Final =[]
for i in izip(list_rank_atp, list_names_atp):
    uitkom = i
    list_Final.append(uitkom)

outfile = open("./tennis.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Rank", "Name"])
writer.writerows(list_Final)
```

The csv output looks as:

[image]

But I want it as:

[image]

Comment: You require input and output as PNG images?

Comment: No, the images was just to show how I want it to look like in csv

Answer (score 2):

Here are some notes :

- XPath index starts from `1`, not `0`. This is why you got empty entry for the first data row.
- You can use Python's `strip()` or XPath's `normalize-space()` to remove spaces around the row number texts

I'd suggest to iterate through rows (`tr`) and get all information needed from current row in every iteration :

```
page = requests.get('http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/rankings/singles')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
outfile = open("./tennis.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)

rows = tree.xpath('//*[@id="rankingDetailAjaxContainer"]/table/tbody/tr')
writer.writerow(["Rank", "Name"])

for row in rows:
    no = row.xpath('td[1]/text()')[0].strip()
    name = row.xpath('td[4]/a/text()')[0]
    writer.writerow([no, name])

outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use strip() method to remove space.